# Inno Setup : The Installed Program Never Launches after Setup Completion

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I have a problem in `[Run] Section` of my Inno Setup Script.

Whether I check or uncheck the CheckBox which appears in the `CurPageID = wpFinished`, my program never launches.

I set the default value of it to `Checked`.

**Parts of my script whose belongs to this :**

```
#define AppExec "hddbsfinder.exe"
#define AppName "HDD Bad Sectors Finder"

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#AppExec}"; Check: CheckLaunching; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(AppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: NoWait PostInstall

function CheckLaunching: Boolean;
begin
  Result := not LauncherCB.Checked;
end;

var    
LauncherCB: TNewCheckbox;

LauncherCB := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
  with LauncherCB do
  begin
    Parent := WizardForm;
    Left := (225);
    Top := (245);
    Width := ScaleX(14);
    Height := ScaleY(15);
  end;

if CurPageID=wpSelectTasks then begin
LauncherCB.Hide;
LauncherCB.Checked := True;
end;

if CurPageID = wpFinished then begin
with WizardForm do begin
LauncherCB.Show;
end;
end;
```

My Program never launches even I check or uncheck that `LauncherCB`.

(The default value is `Checked.`)

**Thanks in Advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Check` parameter of `postinstall` run entries is used to evaluate if to show the checkbox at all, not if to run the entry.

You have two options:

- Implement the launching yourself in the `NextButtonClick(wpFinished)` using the `Exec` function.
- Use the standard run checklist box, just it move to the location you need it at. You will probably need to change the list's `.Parent` to `WizardForm` to remove it from the "Finished" page.

Comment: You didn't tell us what the code should do. Should the program run or not, when the check box is checked? Why do you set it checked? Why do you use a custom check box at all, instead of a standard "run" checkbox on the "finished" page?

Comment: Because my Setup Script is not as Standard one and it contains lot of codes and skins, slideshows and additional tasks...............The `Standard Run CheckBox` is not visible in my Setup's finished page as this page is covered with a large image.Please tell me what is wrong in this code.I want this code to run my program when that checkbox checked and not to run if not checked. And also I want to set its default value as `Checked`.That's what this code SHOULD DO.

Comment: Thank You but the problem is not gone and it has been reversed after changing code as you told.Now the problem is whether I check or uncheck that CheckBox , the program always runs . I know its default value is `Checked`.But when I uncheck this in `wpFinished` page and press "Finish" the program still runs........How can I fix this .........:(